# How to register multiple NgRx stores in a strict mode Angular application?

Tags: angular, ngrx, ngrx-store

After having created a working store service based on `RxJs` and observables, I'm now trying to use the `NgRx` library instead.

The application runs in strict mode and registering the store:

```
StoreModule.forRoot(
  { soundtracks: soundtrackReducer }
),
```

presents a compile time error:

```
Type '(state: SoundtrackState | undefined, action: SoundtrackActions) => SoundtrackState' is not assignable to type 'ActionReducer<SoundtrackState, Action>'.
  Types of parameters 'action' and 'action' are incompatible.
    Type 'Action' is not assignable to type 'SoundtrackActions'.
      Property 'error' is missing in type 'Action' but required in type 'PostFail'.ts(2322)
```

The actions are defined as:

```
export enum SoundtrackActionTypes {
  Add = '[Soundtrack] Add',
  PostFail = '[Soundtrack] Post Fail'
}

export class Add implements Action {
  public readonly type = SoundtrackActionTypes.Add;
  constructor(public soundtrack: Soundtrack) { }
}

export class PostFail implements Action {
  public readonly type = SoundtrackActionTypes.PostFail;
  constructor(public error: HttpErrorResponse) { }
}

export type SoundtrackActions = Add | PostFail;
```

And the reducer:

```
export interface SoundtrackState {
  data: Array<Soundtrack>;
  isLoading: boolean;
  message: string;
}

const initialSoundtrackState: SoundtrackState = {
  data: [],
  isLoading: false,
  message: ''
};

export function soundtrackReducer(state: SoundtrackState = initialSoundtrackState, action: SoundtrackActions): SoundtrackState {
  switch (action.type) {
    case SoundtrackActionTypes.Add: {
      const updatedData: Array<Soundtrack> = [...state['data']];
      updatedData.push(action.soundtrack);
      return {
        ...state,
        data: updatedData,
        isLoading: false,
        message: ''
      };
    }
    case SoundtrackActionTypes.PostFail: {
      return {
        data: [],
        isLoading: false,
        message: 'The soundtrack could not be posted'
      };
    }
    default: {
      return state;
    }
  }
}
```

So I reckoned I should have a custom base action:

```
export interface CustomAction extends Action {
  type: string;
  payload?: any;
  error?: HttpErrorResponse;
}
```

and use it for a post action as:

```
export class PostFail implements CustomAction {
  public readonly type = SoundtrackActionTypes.PostFail;
  constructor(public error: HttpErrorResponse) { }
}
```

But I could not find out how to tell the registering call to consider this custom action.

Other than that, is using a `switch` construct with classes the right way to create actions ? Should I not instead prefer using helper functions ? Something like:

```
export const add = createAction(SoundtrackActionTypes.Add, props<{soundtrack: Soundtrack}>());
export const postFail = createAction(SoundtrackActionTypes.PostFail, props<{error: HttpErrorResponse}>());
```

But then, when creating this reducer:

```
const _soundtrackReducer = createReducer(initialSoundtrackState,
  on(add, (state, { soundtrack }) => {
    const updatedData: Array<Soundtrack> = [...state['data']];
    updatedData.push(soundtrack);
    return {
      ...state,
      data: updatedData,
      isLoading: false,
      message: ''
    };
  }),
  on(postFail, (state, { error }) => {
    return {
      data: [],
      isLoading: false,
      message: 'The soundtrack could not be posted'
    };
  })
);

export function soundtrackReducer(state: SoundtrackState | undefined, action: SoundtrackActions): SoundtrackState {
  return _soundtrackReducer(state, action);
}
```

the registering still complains at compile time of a type mismatch, with the same compile time error.

Also, when registering the store module:

```
StoreModule.forRoot(
  { soundtracks: soundtrackReducer }
),
```

What if I have multiple feature stores ? And a global preferences store as well ? How can I register all these stores ?

UPDATE: I could resolve the compile time error by removing the union type in the reducer signature:

```
export function soundtrackReducer(state: SoundtrackState | undefined, action: Action): SoundtrackState {
  return _soundtrackReducer(state, action);
}
```

Indeed the `SoundtrackActions` union type was not needed.

Comment: What if you'd remove the types from `export function soundtrackReducer(state: SoundtrackState...` ?  Are they really needed there? AFAIK, when using `on(A1, A2, A3, (state, action))` the type of the action would be the union of `A{1 - 3}`

Comment: Yes if removing the types and instead have `export function soundtrackReducer(state: any, action: any)` then the compile time error goes away. But my `SoundtrackActions` type is a union of these action types already. How can I use it in the registering of the store ?

Comment: I don't think you need that union anymore, since the types of the actions are inferred in the `on` function.

Comment: Yes I removed the union altogether.